# Unregister Settings Error

Tags: errors, settings-api, unit-tests

Is it possible to unregister or unset an error that has been added using `add_settings_error`? What I am trying to do is run some unit tests on my settings validation function, but I'd like to reset any errors that may have been added in previous tests in the `teardown` function.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the source of `add_settings_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_error/#source-code), you will see that the errors are stored in the `$wp_settings_errors` global. So in your `tearDown()` function, you can do this:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_settings_errors'] = array();
```

Also, don't forget to call `parent::tearDown()`. I sometimes forget, and it can lead to strange behavior. ;-)

Comment: Works like a charm! Next time I'll go straight to the WordPress source instead of performing random Google searches. Cheers!